# Redirect all subdomains from HTTP to HTTPS using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have domain and its working with https for example

```
http://example.com/
```

Now I am creating sub domains like demo1.example.com, demo2.example.com and so on.

I need all sub domains must be redirect and access by only https.

I have write the code in my .htaccess see below but its always redirecting to the main domain when I access my sub domains.

My htaccess code is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT**

I have main website at root and all other sub-domains code at one of folder. So whenever any sub-domain created that will point to that folder only.

Comment: Try clearling your browser caches ?

Comment: I did multiple times... but no luck.

Comment: My guess: HTTP_HOST does not contain what you think it does, because of the way your subdomains are set up.

Comment: @CBroe How can we get the subdomain, I have tried but not working.

Comment: Do you have a separate .htaccess in subdomain's `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: Yes I have separate .htaccess  for main domain and subdomains folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me. NOTE: if your subdomain has its own .htaccess file (for example a WordPress site in your subdomain), you will have to edit that .htaccess file in addition to the main, domain .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((?!www\.)[^.]+)\.domian\.com$
RewriteRule ^https://%1.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

You can add other rewrite conditions above or below this, depending on when you want them executed.  For example, Reghbendra Nayak's "Handle Front Controller..." code can be placed blow the https 'force' and it will execute.

Answer (score -3):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Because it doesn’t answer the question.

Comment: @MuhammedImranHussain, your solution just didn't work for me.  All subdomains (without their own .htaccess file) did not redirect for me.  I've added my solution below.