# How to forcefully redirect http and www to https

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I am currently using the folowing htaccess to redirect forcefully to https. But this is not redirected to https when the URL is http://www.myexample.com.

How can I change to :

http://www.myexample.com      ->   https://www.myexample.com

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myexample\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myexample.com/$1 [R=301,L]
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redirect all subdomains from HTTP to HTTPS using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40484341/redirect-all-subdomains-from-http-to-https-using-htaccess)

Comment: It's not worked `http://www.myexample.com` remains same

Comment: Your first `RewriteCond`_explicitly_ prevent what you ask for. Why don't you simply remove it? And if that does not work then make sure that you are noot looking at a cached result. So always test with a new anonymous browser window.

Comment: If I removed it, it says too many redirects

Comment: That sounds strange, since the other two conditions prevent exactly that (only `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on` is required actually). So I assume that is some other redirection rule that comes into play here.